# Why no AppSettings in my ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager

I don't know why but i don't have AppSettings in my app.config.file.
If i add it, when i run my apps, appSetting is deleted, so i'm unable to read my data !

Here is my file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<add key="RepertoireEntree" value="E:\DEV\Autres\DevAgréga\Input\*.txt"/>
<add key="RepertoireSortie" value="E:\DEV\Autres\DevAgréga\Output\"/>
</configuration>
```

And in c# :

```
string RepertoireEntree = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RepertoireEntree"];
```

Comment: Have you tried to see during debug mode setting the watch to understand the behavior? How many app.config file you have in a project or this is cross project reading?

Comment: Well, surely that's because you are doing it wrong.  Use Project > Properties > Settings instead and use Properties.Settings.Default.RepertoireEntree in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have your app settings in a `appSettings` element, else it won't be recognized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="RepertoireEntree" value="E:\DEV\Autres\DevAgréga\Input\*.txt"/>
        <add key="RepertoireSortie" value="E:\DEV\Autres\DevAgréga\Output\"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

By the way, it is easier to use settings the usual way. You can do this by creating a settings file from your Project Settings > Settings tab.

Visual Studio will generate the XML elements in the `app.config` for you and you can reference your property like this:

```
string re = Properties.Settings.Default.RepertoireEntree;
```

Comment: Patrick, I think I accidentally hit the downvote but reversed that as second later. Maybe you just saw that.

Comment: Ah, never mind. Doesn't matter too much. right? @Jamiec

Comment: It didn't update straight away. I guess there is some latency issues as I have seen this happening multiple times already.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have your xml correct in the app.config file.

note the start and end tags for appSettings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>



<appSettings>
    <add key="RepertoireEntree" value="E:\DEV\Autres\DevAgréga\Input\*.txt"/>
    <add key="RepertoireSortie" value="E:\DEV\Autres\DevAgréga\Output\"/>
</appSettings>


</configuration>
```

PS

While this is probably not an issue for you (but moreso for future readers)

Make sure you have this reference:

```
Namespace:   System.Configuration
Assembly:  System.Configuration (in System.Configuration.dll)
```

as noted on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: He already has the reference, else `ConfigurationManager` wouldn't be accessible.

Comment: Sometimes I add comments for "later readers", not just the original poster.